# Create a callable function depending on one free parameter from an existing function with many parameters in python

Tags: python

The following is a code in matlab:

```
costFunc = @(p) nnCostFunction(p, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, ...
                               num_labels, X, y, lmbd);
```

it takes the function nnCostFunction, gives it all parameters except p, and turn it into a callable that depends on p.

i.e. you can either call the full function:

```
result = nnCostFunction(p, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size,num_labels, X, y, lmbd)
```

or call the new function:

```
result = costFunction(p)
```

Is there any way to make something similar in Python?

Comment: What exactly is `p` ? And yes, sure it is possible. Read up on `functools.partial` :)

Comment: the name of the variable. i.e. if you wanted to call the regular full function you would have to supply p (in this specific case an array of weights, though I don't think it matters) but if you want to call costFunc, you would call it only with costFunc(p)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

costFunc = partial(nnCostFunction, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, ...
                           num_labels, X, y, lmbd)
```

Then call it with just `p`:

```
costFunc(p)
```

Note, however, that `p` will be passed as the last argument, if you want it to be the first (or somewhere in the middle), you should wrap it in another function:

```
def costFunc(p):
    return nnCostFunction(p, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, ...
                               num_labels, X, y, lmbd)
```